# How to create a template for categories

Tags: categories, templates

I'm developing a custom template and I need to create a custom template for the category list. How can I set a template for this type of pages? The custom template for pages ora articles that I use is via 
`/*
 *Template Name: ARTICLE
 *Template Post Type: post
 */`

Hope someone can help!

EDIT:
I've created a page identical to my blog page but named "category.php". Now, rightly, when I click onto the category it shows me the smae as the blog page: is it possible to edit this query and make only a page "category.php" that queries the right category that i choose?

```
    <?php
get_header();
include_once(get_template_directory() .'/assets/site_parts/common_blocks/head.php'); ?>

<div class="container no-padding blog">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 card">

        <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>            
                <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="post clearfix">

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

                                <div class="blog-top">

                                    <p><?php the_date('d M Y', '<span>', '</span>'); ?></p>

                                        <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>

                                </div></a>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <div class="evidenza cover" style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>)"></div></a>

                            <div class="blog-excerpt">

                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 sidebar">

        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'blog_sidebar' ) ) : ?>

        <div class="sidebar-widget">

            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'blog_sidebar' ); ?>

        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>
<?php
include_once(get_template_directory() .'/assets/site_parts/common_blocks/site-footer.php');
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Clarify the question, please. Do you want to create custom page with list of categories? You can create new page with custom template and add your php code printing categories list

Comment: Sorry for the question, I need to create the page that shows all the articles of the category. In my blog page, there's a sidebar where anyone can choose to sort the articles by category. The sidebar contains the wordpress category widget.

Comment: You can use category.php template. It will shows all posts in the category. If you need to use different templates for different categories, you can use category-{slug}.php and category-{id}.php templates. More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

So for this you'd want to use Category Templates in your theme file, which you can read about in the codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Basically, let's say you have the category "Trending Articles", with the category slug being `trending`. You would want to copy the category template from your current theme (`category.php`, or if that doesn't exist then `archive.php`) into a new file and rename it `category-trending.php`. Then, you can change the header for your own notes.

Once that's added to your theme, it will display that category page when it's searched for. Since you copied the regular category/archive layout it will look the same until you modify the output of that specific file.

I hope this helps!

P.S. - OH! And if you're using a paid theme that will receive updates through an updater, then you'd want to make sure any changes you make are to a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). This prevents your updates from being overwritten if a theme update comes along. You can read a bit more about child themes and download a blank child theme template from the guide [here](https://danielsantoro.com/wordpress-child-theme-template/).

Comment: Thank you man! I build all my themes from scratch so np for child themes!